# Spinner setSelection() not working

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to read my spinner state back in from the sqlite database and then set it if it matches.  I have an array list of array adapters.  I have used debug and ran through the code and everything looks like it is working fine and even giving me the correct indexes.  The only problem is it doesn't change the spinner on the screen.

```
for (int index = 0;  index < listOfAdapters.size(); ++index) {

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = listOfAdapters.get(index);
        for(int j =0; j < adapter.getCount(); ++j)

        if (adapter.getItem(j).equals(state2)){ 
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinner2.setSelection(j);
            return;
        }
    }
```